# Python script taking parameters and keeping state

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I am planning on writing a python script on Raspberry Pi. I have a couple of beginner questions which will help me get on my way.

How does python accept parameters from running py script in a shell?

```
python foodShopping.py eggs milk 8:00
```

How do you maintain state in a script and also pass in new parameters later?

```
python myLights.py
```

console = "Your lights have been activated"

```
python myLights.py toggle
```

console = "Your lights are now off"

```
python myLights.py toggle
```

console = "Your lights are now on"

As you can see toggle will need to keep the original state of the lights.

Thank you.

Comment: To maintain state between different calls of the script you'll need to write some information to the disk, e.g. have it write a file.

Comment: Save the state into another file or database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', nargs='+', help='Food', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--time')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.list
print args.time
```

To run the script like this:

```
python foodShopping.py --list eggs milk --time 8:00
```

You'll got:

```
['eggs', 'milk']
8:00
```